# Ship file with flatpak

Tags: json, flatpak

I have a `json` file with some data that I want to ship with my application.

I want to include it on the folder `/app/share/<app-name>/data/<file>.json`.

I have researched, looked on the flatpak manifest documentation and the manifest of other applications, but I saw no mention to this option.

So, how would be the proper way of adding this file on the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding this file as part of the `"sources"` field in your module, and then installing it.

An example of this in the [Flathub repo for Spotify](https://github.com/flathub/com.spotify.Client/). There, we definitely have a need for shipping separate files that make the integration into your DE seamless, as Spotify doesn't ship those. Concretely, let's look at the desktop launch file that is added:

- The file can be found here: https://github.com/flathub/com.spotify.Client/blob/master/com.spotify.Client.desktop
- You [specify the relative path as a "file" source](https://github.com/flathub/com.spotify.Client/blob/master/com.spotify.Client.json#L158)
- [Add the `install` command](https://github.com/flathub/com.spotify.Client/blob/master/com.spotify.Client.json#L137) to the build-commands field of your module